# How can i predict player retirement from my dataset?

Tags: regression, prediction

I have a dataset from retired players from regional soccer leagues, spanning 293 players from the last 10 years. I have the following variables:

- Team (category, could either be random or fixed)
- Age of retirement, duration (years played), matches played.
- Year of retirement (could be a random factor)

I want to predict the retirement age of players.

This could be a linear regression:

```
Age ~ fixed(duration + caps + Team) + random(Year).
```

But I somehow think that this could be also a logistic model, because my outcome could also be binary (i.e.  still active at age 35?).

How would you set up this model? Which distribution would be appropriate? Some of the predictor variables are counts.

Answer (score 0):

To address your query on the logistic regression first, the only time this would be the case is if you wanted to model age as a binary variable, e.g. 1 for people over a certain age, 0 for those under. If this is not the case, then your variable is not nominal and therefore would not be a binary dependent variable.

While one would need to see your data up close in order to make a determination, the normal distribution would seem appropriate. You could test for the same using a test such as Shapiro-Wilk.

The linear regression you have specified seems fine. With that being said, given that your model is incorporating age as a variable, there is a possibility that your data will show unequal variance across this variable and thus your model should be tested for heteroskedasticity using the Breusch-Pagan test. Also, test your model for multicollinearity with a VIF test to ensure your independent variables are not showing strong correlations with each other.